# How to escape a line from within for loop in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have a for loop in django template where I display items from 3 section by using 'if condition' to filter the 3 sections seperately in the loop. But I want to give a heading to each section but if I add a heading also in the 'if condition' it will be repeated with each item being iterated.
Is there any way to escape the for loop for a single line within the forloop in django template so that the title for each section won't keep repeating.

My django template code:

```
{% for order in orders_today %}

{% if order.pickup_time == 'Now' %}
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"> Orders now </td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
{% if order.pickup_time == 'Now' %}

<tr>
    
    <td align="center">
        {{order.item}}
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        {{order.quantity}}
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        {{order.pickup_time}}
    </td>

    <td align="center">
       
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>

{% if order.pickup_time == 'Lunch Break' %}
<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center"> Orders at lunch break </td>
</tr>
{% endif %}

{% if order.pickup_time == 'Lunch Break' %}

<tr >
    
    <td >
        {{order.item}}
    </td>
    <td >
        {{order.quantity}}
    </td>
    <td >
        {{order.pickup_time}}
    </td>

    <td >
        <button class="btn btn-danger" >Cancel</button>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

thanks in advance to the good soul who's gonna help me ;)

Answer (score 0):

After a walk I've come up with an idea of using nested for loops,
an out loop get's today's date then 3 loops inside the outer loop, each loops filters the items of each break and of that date using if.
I think it'll get the thing done, shall check it's working tomorrow as it's cold late december night today.